# Как забрать значение из таблицы mysql и сделать его переменной js?

Tags: javascript, json

data.php:

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'st');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT st1 FROM st");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ($row["st1"]);

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var q = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/php/data.php';
var returndata;
  $.ajax({
    url: q,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
        returndata = data; 
        console.log(returndata);
        alert(returndata);
    }
  });
});

var st2 = returndata;

var demo = new CountUp("myTargetElement1", 12.52, st2, 0, 6, options);
demo.start();
```

В таблице одно цифровое значение (st1:12000), php отрабатывается, alert выводит значение - 12000. А вот как его дальше поместить в переменную в JS не понятно.

Comment: А приходит ли что-либо сейчас? Что выводят 'console.log и 'alert'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var q = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/php/data.php',
        st2,
        demo;
    $.ajax({
        url: q,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            st2 = data;
            demo = new CountUp("myTargetElement1", 12.52, st2, 0, 6, options);
            demo.start();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Гениально просто. Все забегало. Мерси

Comment: @GrafFoxic если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его как правильный ответ